# Click button within the same HTML structure?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

When return is pressed within a text field I am trying to prevent a line break and instead click the save button.

I have multiple forms with similar layouts. I tried selecting the `textarea` using '.comment-form textarea' then I need to click `:button[value="Save"]` under the same `.comment-form` as the `textarea`.

I have also included my test jQuery, this stops the line break but does not click the button. It also does not differentiate when multiple forms are loaded. I also tried using `parents` to find the `.comment-form` but this also did not work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.comment-form textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(this).blur();
      jQuery(':button[value="Save"]').focus().mousedown();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-wrapper">
  <form class="comment-form">
    <div class="inner-comment-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">...</div>
        <div class="col-11 ">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment </label>
            <div class="form-textarea-wrapper">
              <textarea class="form-textarea" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input name="token">...</input>
      <input name="form-id">...</input>
      <input name="access-id">...</input>
      <div class="author form-group">...</div>
      <div class="form-actions form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-actions">
        <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to target a specific button and trigger an event on it. To make this work you can use `closest()` to get the parent `form` element and `submit()` it.

It's also worth noting that there's some other issues which need to be addressed. Firstly `<input />` elements do not have a closing tag, they are self-closing. Also, the 'Cancel' button is `type="submit"` which seems very odd. I would assume this should be made in to a `type="button"` so that it ***does not*** save the data in the form (which is the main purpose of cancelling an action). Lastly, your HTML was missing a `</form>` tag, but I would guess this was just an oversight when creating the question.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.comment-form textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-wrapper">
  <form class="comment-form">
    <div class="inner-comment-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">...</div>
        <div class="col-11 ">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment </label>
            <div class="form-textarea-wrapper">
              <textarea class="form-textarea" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input name="token" />...
      <input name="form-id" />...
      <input name="access-id" />...
      <div class="author form-group">...</div>
      <div class="form-actions form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-actions">
        <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <button type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for your detailed explaination and help. I can see that your code works when I run the snippet here. When I try it on my website it does not work, if I remove e.preventDefault();, the form is submitted but there is a line break inserted just before it is submitted. I'm not sure why e.preventDefault(); stops ths form from being submitted.